# Sort by multiple fields MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, typescript

In my mongodb i have this situation:

[image: document]

I'd like to sort the *documents* array first by `documents.locale=EN` and then by version desc. 
I am currently using this because I have only two possible locale (IT, EN):

```
return this.model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    documentType: documentType,
                    country: country,
                    'documents.locale': locale
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$documents"
            },
            {
                $sort: {'documents.locale': 1, 'documents.version': -1}
            }
        ]).exec()
```

But what if I have to add an other locale?
How can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mongo dosent offer a built in way to custom sort.

You're going to have to add a new temporary field by nesting [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)'s and sort by it, like so:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        sortLocale: {
            "$cond": [{"$eq":["$type", "EN"]},  1, {"$cond": [{"$eq":["$type", "IL"]}, 2,  3]}]
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can sort on `sortLocale` instead.